# PhoneAuthProvider not working

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-service, firebase-authentication

Hello I am working with Firebase Authentication method of Phone Authentication but when I put  that method that time PhoneAuthProvider given me error that not cannot resolve symbol:

```
  private void resendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber,
                                    PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks,         // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            token);             // ForceResendingToken from callbacks
}
```

I am also

```
 PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
 PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
```

My Firebase version and also add service file:~

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

So how can solve this problem

Comment: please post the error message.

Comment: @bash it does not give me error but can not solve symbol error of PhoneAuthProvider

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the `callbacks`, May be you did, but you haven't shared the code.

```
PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks =new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

    }
};
```

Unless you are trying to resend the verification code. you no need to pass the `token` to this `verifyPhoneNumber` method.

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber,        
        60,                 
        TimeUnit.SECONDS,   
        this,               
        mCallbacks,         
        token); // this token is not needed
```

Use this

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
        60,                 // Timeout duration
        TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
        this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
        mCallbacks,         // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        );
```

By doing this I am getting the verification code to my mobile. If need more help, Please share all the code which is used for phone verification.

Comment: I am using all as its code of  given into this link as its https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android

Comment: Can some one help to move this conversation to chat, I would like to help @HarshitTrivedi